# How can I compute the ideal of this vanishing locus?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and consider $I=(X^2)\subseteq K[X]$. Compute $I(V(I))$, where $I(X):=\{f\in K[X_1,...,X_n]: f(x)=0~~\forall x\in X\}$ and $ V(S):=\{x\in K^n: f(x)=0, \forall x\in X\}$.

Now I know that $V(I)=V((X^2))=\{a\in K^n: f(a)=0~~\forall f\in (X^2)\}$.
But now my first question appears. I know that $(X^2)$ is the smallest ideal that contain $X^2$ but I don't see how $f$ looks like if $f\in (X^2)$.
Is this needed to solve the exercise?

I also know that $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$, but I also don't know how this should look. Is there a good way to compute it with my first approach or should I need the second one?

Comment: @tuvasbien, here would be my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any commutative ring $A$ and any $x\in A$, $(x)=xA$, this means that the elements of $(x)$ can be written as $xa$ where $a\in A$.

Back to your question, $(X^2)=X^2K[X]$ so there is only one element of $K$ that is annihilated by all the elements of $(X^2)$, namely $0$, therefore $V(I)=\{0\}$. Now, $I(V(I))$ is the set of polynomials of $K[X]$ that vanish at $0$, but it is well-known that a polynomial vanishes at, say $a\in K$, iff it is divisible by $X-a$ so $I(V(I))=(X)$.

You could also use the Nullstellensatz which states that $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$ so you only have to prove that $\sqrt{I}=(X)$. It is clear that $(X)\subseteq\sqrt{I}$ (for all $P\in (X)$, $P^2\in (X^2)=I$) so conversely let $P\in \sqrt{I}$. Then $X^2$ divides some power of $P$ but since $K[X]$ is a UFD and $X$ is irreducible, $X$ divides $P$ *i.e.* $P\in (X)$ and you're done.

Comment: ah this makes sense. thanks a lot!